# How make globalSignOut in CognitoAuth - Swift?

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito

I have the next block that is called when user wants signOut:

Im using Swift 5 and call the signOut, but need the globalSignOut.

```
class LoginController: UIViewController{
 var auth: AWSCognitoAuth = AWSCognitoAuth.default()
 var session: AWSCognitoAuthUserSession?

 //..
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.auth.delegate = self
 }

 func signOutAws(){
        self.auth.signOut(self, completion: { (error) in
            if error != nil{
                //show alert..
            }else{
                self.session = nil
                self.auth = AWSCognitoAuth.default()
                self.auth.delegate = self
            }
        })
    }
 //..

}
```

I expect that the user session expired in all apps, but has not expired session in all apps.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_GlobalSignOut.html

can you try out simply replacing signOut with globalSignOut?

Comment: Not possible, globalSignOut is not part of AWSCognitoAuth library, but exist in AWSCognitoIdentityProvider